# Will a cutting or a runner taken from a poorly plant grown in bad soil come good like the parent plant used to be in its youth?

Tags: cuttings, strawberries, potting-mix

Back in April I planted some bare root strawberry plants in my potting soil which turns out to be lacking fertility and probably containing too much salt in the builders sand that I added for drainage. Apparently strawberries are particularly sensitive to salt toxicity and this can frustrate the plants' roots ability to absorb some nutrients effectively.

So my strawberry plants are in terrible shape and I'm curious to know if taking a cutting from a plant generally or potting on one of my plants runners will come good and grow as the young parent plant would've grown had it been raised in good soil.

I know that, normally speaking, a cutting or a runner is a clone, but is it a clone of the young healthy parent or would it's genetic make up have adapted or changed in any way as a result of developing in a poor environment.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin   great!  Thanks. You sound 100% - I'll take that as the answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genetic material does not change in one generation, as [Lamarck](https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-us/question/ascientistwhoworkedonrats-cuttheirtailsupto21successivegenerationsbutatlasthefoundthattail-remainednormalby-giving-thisexperimental-theory-which-of-the-followingscientist-got-disapproved/) was disproved with rat tails.

> This experiment disproves the theory of inheritance of acquired characters, because the tailless condition is an acquired characteristic but it is not inherited by succeeding generations. Lamarck gave theory of inheritance of acquired characters.

Your new plants will grow the plants you bought.

[Not that negative evidence has quelled the debate.](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg16221825-400-cut-off-their-tails/).